# Cohomological dimension of functors from fields to vector spaces

Tags: cohomology, cohomological-dimension

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Denote by $\mathcal F_d$ the category of extensions $K\to F$ of transcendent degree $d$.(Objects are pairs $F,j$ consisting of a field $F$ and the embedding $j\colon K\to F$, such that transcendent degree is equal to $d$, morphisms between $(F_1,j_1)$ and $(F_2,j_2)$ are finite extensions $\psi\colon F_1\to F_2$ such that $\psi\circ j_1=j_2$).  Consider the category of (covariant) functors $Fun(\mathcal F_d, \mathcal{Vect})$ from this category to the category of vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$. What is known about its cohomological dimension?

Especially we have a functor which associate to a field extension $K\to F$ the multiplicative group $(F^\times)\otimes \mathbb Q$. Is it true that all higher cohomology of this functor vanishes?

Comment: $F^{\times}$ is not a vector space...

Comment: Yes, of course. I edited the question. Or we can study the same question with abelian groups instead of vector spaces.

Comment: I don't understand the category $\mathcal F_d$. How can finite extensions be morphisms between extensions?

Comment: I edited question. Is it clear now?